# Jss function with return string

Tags: javascript

I have to create function sayHello in Js, which will return text "Hello" + with text parametr. So if i put f.e. Thomas it will return "Hello Thomas", but if i dont put any text, it will return "Hello Wolrd".
I have to mention im totaly fresh with jss, and this is a code i came up with.

```
function sayHello(o) { 
return 'Hello' + o;
if (o = 'Tomek ') return 'Hello Tomek';
else if (o = ' ') return 'Hello World';
}
```

But when i try it i will get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tomek is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:10
```

Ok i add a screenshot to show an error.

```
https://imageupload.io/ROju6ly0M1.i
```

Comment: While there are certainly things wrong with the code shown, the one thing it doesn't do is produce the error shown.

Comment: Please provide more context. how are you calling this function? The error you show is not generated from the snippet you show.

Comment: I got a ss, and i got this error https://imageupload.io/ROju6ly0M1.i

Comment: @Panasiux2: You get that error on the one line of code you're *not* showing in the question.  `Tomek` is indeed not defined.  Notice how in the working code you enclose your string value in quotes, but in the non-working code you don't enclose your string value in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your function.

1. "return" exits the function and therefore cannot go before the logic.
2. The single equal is an assignment and not a comparison. You have to use the equal triple (===).

Just to name a few.

A correct version:

```
function sayHello(name) {
  name = name || 'World'; // Check if null.
  return 'Hello ' + name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you must create a function that takes a name argument. You can assign a default to that argument e.g. "World". After you receive the argument, you can return the phrase to print out.

```js
const sayHello = (name = 'World') => `Hello ${name}!`;

console.log(sayHello('Thomas')); // Hello Thomas!
console.log(sayHello());         // Hello World!
```

Here is the legacy way (pre-ES5):

```js
function sayHello(name) {
  name = name || 'World'; // If name is null or undefined, use default
  return 'Hello ' + name;
}

console.log(sayHello('Thomas')); // Hello Thomas!
console.log(sayHello());         // Hello World!
```

---

### Edit

Since no one actually showed you how to fix your code (guilty...), here is your function with the corrections wit the least amount of changes:

If you want to keep the else-if condition for `" "`, then you should move the initial return statement to the end of the function. If you have an if-else-if without a final else, your function will return `undefined`.

```js
function sayHello(o) {                     // OK!
  //return 'Hello' + o;                    // Do not return early
  if (o === 'Tomek') return 'Hello Tomek'; // Use "==" or better "==="
  else return 'Hello World';               // No need for an else-if
}                                          // OK!

console.log(sayHello('Tomek'));            // "Hello Tomek"
console.log(sayHello());                   // "Hello World"
```

Comment: Thank you, i have additional question, i see you put a name = name, so jss can recognize a name i put in f.e. ```console.log(sayHello('Thomas'));

Comment: @Panasiux2 Functions parameters in ES5+ can have default values assigned to them. Also, I added an update to the bottom for a better explanation of the issues you were facing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know the syntax and basics of any language. You can write the method like this:

```
function sayHello(name = 'World') {
   return `Hello ${name}`;
}
```

There can be different ways to create functions in JS. But this one is sometjing similar that you have seen in other languages;I would suggest you to use this link to understand the basics of JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Do not link to [w3fools](https://www.w3fools.com), instead you should link to [MDN Web Docs - Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)